Don't have permission to view all the namespaces in the cluster
I tried to add gitlab-agent to the environment and select the namespace and flux customization there, but I get errors
Errors
I'm using the Gitlab hosted version of Self-Manager on Kubernetes.
Install command gitlab-agent
helm upgrade --install h gitlab/gitlab-agent \
    --namespace gitlab-agent-h \
    --create-namespace \
    --set image.tag=v17.2.2 \
    --set config.token=token \
    --set config.kasAddress=wss://kas.domain.com

Configuration gitlab-agent to path .gitlab/agents/my-agent/config.yaml in repository
user_access:
  access_as:
    agent: {}
  groups:
    - id: LearnHub
    - id: LearnHub/Frontend
    - id: LearnHub/Identity
ci_access:
  groups:
    - id: LearnHub
    - id: LearnHub/Frontend
    - id: LearnHub/Identity

Install command flux
flux bootstrap gitlab \
--hostname=gitlab.domain.com \
--owner=Flux-LearnHub \
--repository=Flux \
--branch=main \
--path=clusters/production \
--deploy-token-auth

Adding a repository
flux create source git learnhub-mainpage \
  --url=https://gitlab.domain.com/learnhub/frontend/mainpage.git \
  --branch=main \
  --interval=1m \
  --namespace=flux-system \
  --username=username \
  --password=token

flux create kustomization learnhub-mainpage-kustomization \
  --source=GitRepository/learnhub-mainpage.flux-system \
  --path="./manifests" \
  --prune=true \
  --interval=5m \
  --namespace=flux-system

And I don’t see Flux customization or namespace in the selection
I tried to manually grant the gitlab-agent cluster admin role for testing
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: gitlab-agent-cluster-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: learnhub-gitlab-agent # name ServiceAccount
  namespace: gitlab-agent

And I made sure that gitlab-agent has rights to all namespaces, but still nothing appears in the list, tell me how to fix this.
I also noticed that all requests that access gitlab kas return with error 401, and this specifically applies to those requests for which I created a question.
https://kas.domain.com/k8s-proxy/api/v1/namespaces
https://kas.domain.com/k8s-proxy/apis/kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1/namespaces/gitlab-agent/kustomizations
https://kas.domain.com/k8s-proxy/apis/helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1/namespaces/gitlab-agent/helmreleases

General answer
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "GitLab Agent Server: Unauthorized: no valid credentials provided",
  "reason": "Unauthorized",
  "code": 401
}

